# wso2 data service dynamic query parameter

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm newbie to WSO2 Data Service.
I'm trying use the SQL Query with a parameter but I have an error:

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue executeUpdate() for SELECTs

my sql query is :

```
<query id="countryByName" useConfig="testDatasource">
      <sql>select id from country where name = ?</sql>
      <param name="name" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Hello

Gordon

Answer (score 1):

Here you are invoking a select query , but result is not specified. Hence dataservice is trying to do a executeUpdate() on select which fails. So when you are doing a select, make sure to define the output mapping according to the columns returned by the query .Here specify the result of the query as 'id'.

```
  <query id="countryByName" useConfig="testDatasource">
      <sql>select id from country where name = ?</sql>
      <result element="Countries" rowName="Country">
         <element column="id" name="id" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
      <param name="name" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
```